# how to create a login appliaction for iphone without others frame work

Tags: iphone

my application should accept user name and password...connect to server.then diasplay details from server..

i have done using XML parser .from server i will get XML file in my i phone using parser i displayed..now i need check for name an d password.so i don't have idea to create interface and all...so guide..me am going mad in it

Comment: We're not here to write your application for you.  Refine this to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to look in a example and pick what you want to use there.
http://iphone.wordpress.org/development/

But basically what you want to do is to create two text fields and a button for login?
Then send a request with xml and parse the response if they where sucessfull or not.
If successfull go ahead and show the views that they cant view otherwise.

Not sure if this answers your question or not but thats how i would do it.